# int not subscriptable when trying to remove item from list

Tags: python-2.7, list, subscript

I'm reading a file `outputfromextract`and I want to split the contents of that file with the delimiter ',' which I have done.

When reading the contents into a list there's two 'faff' entries at the beginning that I'm just trying to remove however I find myself unable to remove the index

```
import json

class device:
   ipaddress = None
   macaddress = None
   def __init__(self, ipaddress, macaddress):
       self.ipaddress = ipaddress
       self.macaddress = macaddress

listofItems = []
listofdevices = []


def format_the_data():
    file = open("outputfromextract")
    contentsofFile = file.read()
    individualItem = contentsofFile.split(',')
    listofItems.append(individualItem)
    print(listofItems[0][0:2]) #this here displays the entries I want to remove
    listofItems.remove[0[0:2]] # fails here and raises a TypeError (int object not subscriptable)
```

In the file I have created the first three lines are enclosed below for reference:

```
[u' #created by system\n', u'time at 12:05\n', u'192.168.1.1\n',...
```

I'm wanting to simply remove those two items from the list and the rest will be put into an constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `listofItems.remove[0[0:2]]` should be `listofItems.remove[0][0:2]`.

**But**,  slicing will be much easier, for example:

```
with open("outputfromextract") as f:
    contentsofFile = f.read()
    individualItem = contentsofFile.split(',')[2:]
```

Comment: I forgot you could slice on that method, I contemplated it but thought it crazy and moved onto other means